# C++ macro to fail when a subclass hasn't used another macro

Tags: c++, c++11, macros

I have a class `X` declared in `x.h` and defined in `x.cpp` that has to run some code (registering some class metadata in a centralized place) in the static initialization phase using macro `INIT(X)`. The same goes for any subclass `Y` (declaration in `y.h`, including `x.h`, definition in `y.cpp`) of `X` - it has to run `INIT(Y)` in the global scope. Now I want to create a static check if every subclass has been initialized. And additionally I do not know how many of `X` subclasses will I be linking.

I want to define a macro in `x.h` that will generate a compiler error if there exists a `SubClass` of `X` (or any other descendant of `X`) that hasn't called `INIT(SubClass)`. How to do it?

Requirements:

- C++11.
- It can be required to call it in `subclass.cpp` file if needed.
- It can be required that `SubClass` has its whole definition in `subclass.cpp`.
- The compilers I want to support are at least `gcc` and `msvc`.
- It should not generate an error in `someotherclass.cpp` that imports `x.h` unless it defines a subclass of `X`.
- The error may be any kind of compiler error, it doesn't necessarily have to be `#error`, e.g. undefined variable is also fine.
- The code of this macro may require additional changes in the `X` class, but not in any of its subclasses.
- `INIT` must work when put in any place in `subclass.cpp` after all includes.

Defining a dummy abstract method in a new base class of `X` would work if only I didn't have the requirement to not modify any of `X`'s subclasses to put its declaration there and definition in `INIT`.

Below is a template code for that design where `INIT` is simply used to count number of linked `X` subclasses + 1. `/*???*/` may be substituted with anything, as long as it works.

`x.h`:

```
#include <functional>

int &someGlobalInt();

class XInit {
public:
    XInit(std::function<void ()> init) {
        init();
    }
};

#define INIT(cls) static XInit X_INIT_ ## cls = XInit([](){ \
    ++someGlobalInt(); \
    /*???*/ \
})

class X {
    /*???*/
};
/*???*/
```

`x.cpp`:

```
#include "x.h"

int &someGlobalInt() {
    static int x = 0;
    return x;
}

INIT(X); // error without it
```

`y.h`:

```
#include "x.h"
class Y: public X {};
```

`y.cpp`:

```
#include "y.h"
INIT(Y); // error without it
```

`main.cpp`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "x.h"
// no error, since no new X subclass is defined
int main() {
    printf("%d\n", someGlobalInt()); // should print "2"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: fyi, according to the standards items beginning with a double underscore are reserved.

`17.6.3.3.2 Global names [global.names]`

`— Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.`

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll change it. But the main question still remains.

Comment: @Xilexio I don't have the time right now, but if this remains unanswered later this evening, I'll try to come up with a solution for you.

Comment: This is probably impossible. There are lots of variations of the theme "force each derived class of ABC do XYZ once". I have never seen any such thing working. You may be able to achieve something by using CRTP `class Y: public XInit<Y> {...` so that `XInit` code takes care about each derived class by e.g. having a static variable with an initializer that depends on that class.

Comment: Your statement about static initialization phase, did you really mean that? Keep in mind that unless X is a trivial type, it cannot be statically initialized. Another issue: namespace level code in .cpp files is a really dangerous practice (unless constructing trivial types). I also don't know if what you're asking is possible with literally zero modification of Y. I can provide you some pretty good robust suggestions though if you can be a little flexible, and confirm you don't really mean static initialization.

Comment: @NirFriedman I produce a complicated framework for objects based on `X` and I want other developers that make subclasses of `X` to not write any repetitive code needlessly. There will be a lot of `X` subclasses and different subsets of them will be used in a few separate projects. So, since for my framework I need static data for each X subclass, I came up with this solution. More specifically, I'm working in Qt 5 and want to gather `Y::staticMetaObject` for all subclasses linked in each project and make a tree out of them. This is what I do in my real version of `INIT` macro.

Comment: @n.m. That seems like a good starting point, but by itself it'll have a problem that a subclass of subclass of `X` will inherit two initializers. And I'll be working on a large class tree with depth up to 5-7.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem as the initializer should not have any non-static data members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As n.m. mentioned in the comments, you can use Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. You can do something like this, which I think is clearer than messing around with these lambdas:

XInit.h

```
template <class T>
class XInit {
  private:
    static bool initialized;
    static std::once_flag flag;
    static void base_init<T>(){ std::call_once(flag, T::reserved_init);}
 ...
}
```

XInit.cpp

```
template <class T>
XInit<T>::initialized = XInit<T>::base_init();
```

Now you can define your macro as:

```
#define INIT(cls) static void reserved_init() {++someGlobalInt();}
```

Now you inherit:

```
class X : public XInit<X> ...
```

Note that if you need hierarchy, that's fine, just do:

```
class Y: public X, public XInit<Y>
```

Notice that there isn't any multiple inheritance here, because `XInit<X>` and `XInit<Y>` are different classes. The actual work is done in the new base classes we keep spawning. Now, the base class will always attempt to call it's derived class' static reserved_init member. So if this member is not defined, you get an error. Therefore, you need to put the macro in the class definition.

As always, if the user really wants to, they can get around this. They can define another function with the same name, for example. Ultimately I don't think you can create a system that is deliberate-abuse proof, but it should work against honest mistakes. Let me know what you think of this solution, maybe I can  introduce modifications to fix it.

Comment: But that doesn't force you to inherit from `XInit<Y>` in `Y`, does it? Compiler will compile it perfectly fine if user doesn't know about `XInit` and `INIT` and just don't add it. Then it doesn't serve its purpose - reminding developer of a subclass about `INIT` or `XInit<Y>`. I already have the code that works if you just remember that fact (though I agree that you have more clean solution than mine for that).

Comment: I need the functionality that n.m. mentioned: "force each derived class of ABC do XYZ once" - the "force" part is still missing.

Comment: I mean, the way I set it up, it forces registration for all children of XInit. If you want to force it for all children of X, then get rid of XInit completely and implement its functionality inside X. Then X will be a templated class, and when you inherit from X, you will need to template X on the derived type.

Comment: That would work for children. But there are few problems: I don't see it working for descendants lower than children (`class Z: public Y, public XInit<Z>` and doesn't make error on `class Z: public Y`), you have to declare `reserved_init` inside each descendant, forces you to implement the main class in a header file (template). The last one can be probably solved by solving the first problem. A solution that works only for children can be made by simply adding dummy pure virtual method - you are reminded to implement it (plus some junk like declaration, but that's the same for `XInit<Y>`).

Comment: A dummy pure virtual method doesn't solve what you're suggesting, because virtual methods cannot be static. Trying to do this initialization with non-static methods makes no sense and has several issues. I just doubt it's possible to force users in the way you mean, and even if it was possible I doubt it's worth it. An interface should be easy to use correctly and hard to use incorrectly, but not impossible. Fundamentally in C++ children have to be aware of their ancestors to construct them, but there is no forced awareness of children by parents.

Comment: Also: it's pretty much impossible in C++ to ever have an interface that's impossible to abuse... consider that for example you can cast away constness in one line.

Comment: I mean a dummy virtual method as in declaring `virtual void rememberToPutINITInCPPFile() = 0` and then adding to macro `INIT` its empty definition `void cls::rememberToPutINITInCPPFile() {}`. That method would not be used for actual initialization, but for the error. And I don't want interface that's impossible to abuse. I want to force all descendant classes to register in one place at the start of the program and make compiler check that. Assuming user did not want to work around it, but could have simply just not read the documentation that he has to use `INIT`.